# SQL Server 2008 Express uninstall error: network resource unavailable

Tags: sql-server-2008, uninstall

I am trying to uninstall SQL Server 2008 Express but it fails with an error saying that a network resource in unavailable. It is trying to find some msi's on an installation disk but I installed with the new web platform installer so there is no installation files on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried downloading SQL Server 2008 Express (non-web-platform edition) and running an install/uninstall?

Comment: Good idea but it did not work for me. I am going to wipe the laptop this weekend. It won't let me update visual studio 2008 to sp1 either.